# WP_Query returns no results

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to retrieve some pages in wordpress using `WP_Query` and some arguments:

```
$args = array(
   'post_type' => 'posttype',
   'posts_per_page' => 24,
   'post__in'      => $store_ids,
   'paged' => $paged,
   'post_status' => 'publish',
);

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

The pages I'm trying to retrieve here should match an ID in an array of ID's I have given it. The array and other arguments seem fine since I do get my results when I use `get_posts` instead of `WP_Query`. What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

My educated guess is that you have a poorly written filter somewhere in your theme that is acting on `WP_Query`, and it is most probably the action `pre_get_posts`.

`get_posts` makes use of `WP_Query`. The only difference is that `get_posts` passes the following two arguments to `WP_Query` by default:

- `'no_found_rows' => true` which "fails" pagination, that is why you can't paginate `get_posts`
- `'suppress_filters' =>true` This is the important one, what this does is, it stops filters from altering the query. So `pre_get_posts` and the build in `posts_*` filters cannot be used to alter `get_posts`. This is why in your case you get posts using `get_posts` and none using `WP_Query`

The dirty fix here is to add `'suppress_filters' => true` to your query arguments in `WP_Query`. The correct fix will be is to look for the filter altering the query. As I said, most probably `pre_get_posts` where you did not use the `is_main_query()` check to just target the main query

Comment: Excellent answer! My problem was indeed that some filtering took place elsewhere. Your explanation is very clear and gives me a better understanding of what was going on.

Comment: Thanks. I am glad that my answer was useful to you. :-)