# Ordering custom post types

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I'm registering a new custom post type like this:

```
function news_register() {
    $labels = array(
        'name' => _x('News', 'post type general name'),
        'singular_name' => _x('News Item', 'post type singular name'),
        'add_new' => _x('Add New News Article', 'resources item'),
        'add_new_item' => __('Add New News Article'),
        'edit_item' => __('Edit News Article'),
        'new_item' => __('New News Article'),
        'view_item' => __('View News Article'),
        'search_items' => __('Search News Articles'),
        'not_found' =>  __('Nothing found'),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __('Nothing found in Trash'),
        'parent_item_colon' => ''
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'public' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'menu_position' => 8,
        'supports' => array('title','editor', 'excerpt', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt')
    ); 
    register_post_type( 'news' , $args );
}
add_action('init', 'news_register');
```

And I'm then trying to query those post types and order them by title using:

```
$news = new WP_Query(array(
      'post_type'  => 'news',
      'orderby'    => 'name',
      'order'      => 'DESC'
  ));
```

Or:

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'news', 'posts_per_page'=>5, 'orderby'=>'title','order'=>'ASC');
$news = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Neither of which order by the post title at all. The news posts are test articles that are called 'aaa', 'bbb' and 'ccc.

How can I change my query to get the posts by title order?

EDIT:

I have this code in functions, but removing it doesn't seem to change anything.

add_filter( 'pre_get_posts','change_my_post_order' );

```
function change_my_post_order( $query ) {
    global $wp_query;

    if ( is_category() ) {
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'title' );
        $query->set( 'order', 'asc' );
    }

    return $query;
}
```

Adding "'suppress_filters' => true," to the query doesn't seem to make any difference either.

Comment: Maybe you have [this problem](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30213886/1908141) as your query is correct

Comment: Had a look and it seems like a solution but I can't see any changes regardless of what I try. Made an edit showing what I had in functions.php

Comment: Your `pre_get_posts` function is definitely wrong

Comment: In what way? I didn't build the site originally and am unsure what the purpose of it would even be. To attempt to force an order onto all posts? Why would removing it entirely not resolve the ordering query issues?

Comment: Have you tried `get_posts`. Do you get the same result

Answer (score 0):

Your `pre_get_posts` action is wrong. You should make sure that you only target the front end and only the main query. Your action should look like this

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts','change_my_post_order' );

function change_my_post_order( $query ) {

    if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && $query->is_category() ) {
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'title' );
        $query->set( 'order', 'asc' );
    }
}
```